# Angular JS : Unknown Provider

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am having issues trying to minify my Angular app. The error I am receiving is:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scope, dataServiceProvider <- $scope, dataService
```

My App:

```
angular.module('Forms', [
'ngRoute',
'Forms.Services',
'Forms.Directives',
'Forms.Controllers'
])
```

My Service is:

```
angular.module('Forms.Services', []).
service('dataService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.getData = function(callback) {
        $http.get('forms.json').success(callback);
    }
}]);`
```

My Controller is:

```
angular.module('Forms.Controllers', []).
controller('FormController', ['$scope, dataService', function ($scope, dataService) {

    dataService.getData(function(results) {
        $scope.data = results;
    });

}])
```

It is working fine without the Array notation but as you know it will not minify.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take some care on properly formatting your posts (I fixed it for you this time, you can look it up in the edit history). Apart from this: I do not really understand the problem. Are you minifying and then your code doesn't work or does it not minify (if the latter, you might want to show us how you minify your code...). If the first, well, the minifying process and the resulting JS might also be relevant.

Comment: @dirkk The issue was fixed with the below response, I had set up the dependency injection incorrectly causing the error I spoke of. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be:

```
controller('FormController', ['$scope', 'dataService', function //...
```

instead of:

```
controller('FormController', ['$scope, dataService', function //...
```

Note that the dependencies are listed as separate strings in the array, not as a single string.